# MS-SQL stored procedure throwing error after adding a new Join statement. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 279 Incorrect syntax near 'WHERE'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, outer-join

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 279 
> Incorrect syntax near 'WHERE'.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Country_usp_GetLocationsDetailsTemp] 

            (@RiskID nvarchar(50)

            ,@LocationID nvarchar(50)

            ,@SortColumn nvarchar(50)

            ,@SortOrder nvarchar(5)

            ,@PageIndex nvarchar(5)

            ,@MaxRows nvarchar(5))

AS

declare @sql1 nvarchar(max)

declare @sql2 nvarchar(max)
    

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        if( @SortColumn = 'Description') begin set @SortColumn = 'PL.Description' end

        set @sql1 = '

        ;with LocationResults as

        (

                SELECT 

                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SortColumn + ' ' + @SortOrder + ') AS RowNumber

                      ,PL.RiskID as RiskID
                      
                      , [LocationID]


                      ,HMLC.Description  as ''Country'' 

                      
                      set @sql2 = ' ,EarthQuake as EarthQuakeID

                                    ,HRIF.ProgramID


                  FROM [Country_Locations] PL
                  
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN Country_Master_Common HMLC on  HMLC.ColumnName = ''Country'' and HMLC.Code = Country and HMLC.active = 1
                                  
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN Country_RiskInformation HRIF ON hrif.active = 1 and hrif.riskid = ''' + @RiskID + '''

                                  
                                                  WHERE 

                  (''' + @RiskID + '''= '''' or PL.RiskID =''' + @RiskID + ''')

                  AND ('''+@LocationID+''' = '''' or LocationID = '''+@LocationID+''')

                  AND PL.Active = 1

        )

          SELECT * FROM LocationResults
          
          WHERE

                  RowNumber BETWEEN('+@PageIndex+' -1) * '+@MaxRows + '+ 1 AND((('+@PageIndex+' -1) * '+@MaxRows+' + 1) + '+@MaxRows+') - 1'


          exec (@sql1 + @sql2)

          
          print @sql1

          print @sql2
```

This is the formula to calculate results to be displayed based on pagination.

This formula breaking down after adding new Join statement.

But as per my knowledge there is no issue with my Join, because if I try executing the printed SQL with actual values in formula like:

```
SELECT * FROM LocationResults WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 and 5
```

Its working fine.

Note: All Joins I'm using in the SP are Left outer Join.

I'd like to know where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That SQL isn't valid. `'+@PageIndex+' -1)`? `'+@PageIndex+'` is a literral string, how to you subtract `1` from it? It's like having `'Apples' - 2`.

Comment: Also, there' nothing about where the `WHERE` is that'll generate that error. I would expect the error to be *"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '+@PageIndex+' to data type int."*

Comment: Added the code to regenerate the error. kindly re-open the question.

Comment: '+@pageIndex+' will receive actual value from the backend code, actually this pattern '+@pageIndex+' is working fine, if we remove the below join statement from sp                               LEFT OUTER JOIN Country_RiskInformation HRIF ON hrif.active = 1 and hrif.riskid = ''' + @RiskID + '''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query was getting truncated because of lengthy code.
Adding a new variable and assigning the last query of the sp to new variable resolved the issue.

sql3= 'SELECT * FROM LocationResults WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 and 5
'